# Find values not present in multiple spill lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of usernames (which will contain duplicates)  - beginning A2 in the image - and then three lists of usernames generated by spill functions of particular types of problems (again these can contain duplicates) - spill formulae in C2, E2, G2 in the image.

What I want is a list of unique usernames from the list in A that do not appear in any of the C, E or G lists.  I was hoping I could use a `unique` as the array for a `filter` - something like:

`=filter(unique(a:a), (ROW(a:a)>1)*<not in c2 spill>*<not in e2 spill>*<not in g2 spill>`

This is being developed for extremely non-technical users - it's taken long enough to show them how to copy and paste the list of usernames into column A (which will be deleted then repopulated roughly monthly) so ideally there would be a solution where there's no further actions needed when column A is repopulated.

[image: Cut down version of the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is good. You can use a formula like this:

```
=LET(data,A2:A100, UNIQUE(FILTER(data, (data<>"")*(COUNTIF(C2#,data)=0)
*(COUNTIF(E2#,data)=0)*(COUNTIF(G2#,data)=0))))
```

Choose appropriate data range which is sufficient for your needs.
[image: usernames]